# Delphi styled speedbuttons lose transparency on MacOS

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

Drop a speedbutton on a form. Set the stylelookup to composetoolbutton.

The button renders correctly on Windows, but transparency is missing on MacOS.

Any way to work around that?

Comment: I recall that they are styled that way. The style makes them non-transparent on MacOS.

Comment: If you are using system style, then you can't expect certain elements to look the same on all systems.

Comment: While I certainly don't expect system style elements to look the same across all systems but I do expect them to behave the same on all systems. Transparency failing just because it's a certain platform does not seem correct.